# Could not deduce (a ~ Double) with Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, typeclass

I have a typing problem with a Haskell function.
I implemented this (simplified) function :

```
function (xa,ya,za) (xb,yb,zb) (Size tai) = function (xa,ya,za) (xb,yb,zb) (Ndiv ndiv)
  where 
        ndiv = ceiling (leng / tai)
        leng = sqrt((xb-xa)**2+(yb-ya)**2+(zb-za)**2)

data Method = Ndiv Int
            | Size Double
```

It working well if I give my `function` this signature :

```
function :: (Double,Double,Double) -> (Double,Double,Double) -> Method -> [(Double,Double,Double)]
```

Now, I would like to extend my function to the whole `Num` class. I forced the type with :

```
function :: Num a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> Method -> [(a,a,a)]
```

and when compiling, GHC give me the following error :

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for
             function :: Num a =>
                         (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a) -> Method -> [(a, a, a)]
  at Type.hs:7:13-62
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        function :: Num a =>
                    (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a) -> Method -> [(a, a, a)]
      at Type.hs:7:13
In the second argument of `(/)', namely `tai'
In the first argument of `ceiling', namely `(leng / tai)'
In the expression: ceiling (leng / tai)
```

I never had a such error and I'm a bit disappointed.
I suspect a class conflict/mismatch but I don't see how to solve it ?

**Do you know what is wrong with my function and how to make it work?**

Comment: The `tai` parameter is fixed to `Double` because of your datatype. Change it to `data Method a = Ndiv Int | Size a`, for example, then your function should typecheck, although you'll need a stronger constraint than `Num`, `cieling` requires `RealFrac`. The type will be `RealFrac a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> Method a -> [(a,a,a)] `

Comment: @user2407038 you should put this into an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tai` parameter is fixed to `Double` because of your datatype. Change it to

```
data Method a = Ndiv Int | Size a
```

for example, then your function should typecheck, although you'll need a stronger constraint than `Num`, as `cieling` requires `RealFrac`. The type will be

```
function :: RealFrac a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> Method a -> [(a,a,a)]
```